# How to Change Release Name format in tfs release dashboard?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, dashboard, release-management

Is there any way to change the Release name of Pipeline after it started and dash board will still consider the new name and reflect it ?
For example at the start of the build ReleaseName=release_1 and after that in one of the step we change its value to ReleaseName=release_11.04122018 but release dashboard will still be having older ReleaseName, how can it be updated with changed name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To customize the build and release names, you could consider using the commands of `build.updatebuildnumber` and respectively `release.updatereleasename` from a PowerShell script. See also this page on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

Translated to yaml, it'll look like this:

```
- powershell: |
    [string]$version="$(Build.Repository.Name)_SomeCustomData_$(Build.BuildId)"
    Write-Output "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$version"
  displayName: Set Build Number
```

Same applies for setting a release number, but since it's not possible yet to use yaml for release pipelines, you'd need to add a PowerShell task yourself and add an inline script like this:

```
[string]$name="My custom release name"
Write-Output "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$name"
```

To see which variables you can use for build and release pipelines, check these pages:

- [Build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#build-variables)
- [Release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#release-variables)

Comment: For updating the release name of pipeline, the minimum agent pool version should be  2.132, you can write the inline as  "##vso[release.updatereleasename]release name"

Comment: Thank you! However, this command is not supported in TFS, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md